R mice code for delta sensitivity analysis for a binary variable : apparently not working
I am performing multiple imputation on my dataset with R mice prior to carrying out my primary analysis which is a binary logistic regression with functional decline as outcome and a number of variables as predictors (continuous and binary). I am using pmm for continuous variables/logreg for binary variables, m=5, maxit=10 and a fixed seed  for reproducibility.
I need to perform a sensitivity analysis with a delta-adjustment for the outcome functional decline assuming that the missing are more likely to be decliners by an amount that I have calculated to be equal to log=4.3 according to Rezvan et al. [http://dx.doi.org/10.14301/llcs.v9i3.503]
I am not an expert in writing code for R so to customize the mice.impute.logregfunction I used the code available in a paper by Leacy et al.(https://doi.org/10.1093/aje/kww107). The whole code can be found below. Although it runs without error messages I believe it is not working, based on a number of "checks" I have made (I have enumerated them at the end of this post). Can someone help me understand where my mistake is?
Please note that increasing the number of iterations and of imputations (maxit=20, m=50) and changing the visiting sequence do not substantially change the results. Also, I found no such inconsistencies between the code and my "checks" when I ran sensitivity analyses for some of the (continuous) variables in my dataset (following the code in a mice vignette:https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Sensitivity_analysis/Sensitivity_analysis.html]
#customizing the mice.impute.logreg function according to Leacy et al
library(mice)
mice.impute.logreg.sens <- function(y, ry, x, delta,...) { 
 x <- cbind(1, as.matrix(x)) 
expr <- expression(glm.fit(x[ry, ], y[ry], family = binomial(link = logit))) 
fit <- suppressWarnings(eval(expr)) 
fit.sum <- summary.glm(fit) 
beta <- coef(fit) 
beta[1]<-beta[1]+ delta
rv <- t(chol(fit.sum$cov.unscaled))
beta.star<-beta + rv %% rnorm(ncol(rv))
p <- 1/(1 + exp(-(x[!ry, ] %% beta.star))) 
vec <- (runif(nrow(p)) <= p)  
vec[vec] <- 1  
if (is.factor(y)) { 
vec <- factor(vec, c(0, 1), levels(y))} 
return(vec)}``

#applying it to my dataset and carrying out the binary logistic regression (note: here I have simplified the dataset for the reprex)
myvars<-c ("FunctionalDecline", "Age", "Sex", "GDS4")  
realdataset<-dataset [myvars]  
realdataset$FunctionalDecline<-factor(realdataset$FunctionalDecline)  
realdataset$Sex<-factor(realdataset$Sex)  
ini<-mice(realdataset, maxit=0)  
meth<-ini$meth  
meth["FunctionalDecline"]="logreg.sens"  
imputeddataset<-mice(realdataset, meth=meth,seed=3, m=5, maxit=10, delta=log(4.3), print=F) 
summary(pool(with(imputeddataset, glm (FunctionalDecline~Age+ Sex + GDS4, family=binomial))))`

Reasons why the code appears to be not working properly

With delta=log(1.0) (i.e.no adjustment=MAR)the results of the logistic regression are different than those of the logistic regression on the dataset with no delta adjustment

After the delta-adjustment all predictors in the binary logistic regression lose significance. If, however, I do a "rougher" worst-scenario sensitivity analysis by putting all imputed functional decline values equal to 1 (i.e decline) most predictors retain significance. This remains true whatever method I use to put all imputed functional decline values equal to 1 (post-imputation or within the imputation using the "post" function from mice)

If, to approximate the worst scenario analysis, I assume 99% of decliners among the missing and use the corresponding delta=log 280 in the R code, the results are totally inconsistent with the "rougher" worst-scenario analysis described in 2.


